# A mp4-file messing up appcache setup

Tags: html, apache, google-chrome, mobile-safari, html5-appcache

I'm trying to make an offline webapp for Mobile Safari mainly. I have my .appcache file set up  and it's working fine until I add a line for a .mp4 -file (52 mb). Even Desktop Chrome will fail appcaching the app 'cause of the file - it gives an error:

```
Application Cache Error event: Resource fetch failed (-1)
```

And because that fails, the whole appcaching fails.

Using a http sniffer (HTTPScoop) I found out that around 30 mb the downloading of the mp4 stops, and gives "Reset by peer" -error.

Does it have something to do with Apache, with the browser, the ISP or what?

Comment: could you possibly look at my answer and possibly accept it? It has been there for 13 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to one of the people who posted something [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?hl=en#!topic/chromium-html5/iT-jTQNSh9Q), Chrome has a 260mb total appcache size limit and about 32mb per-file limit (which is about when you said the download stopped). I don't know about other browsers, but in Chrome you can fix this by creating a chrome app. It seems inconvenient and annoying, but it is the only way to increase that limit. Not sure if that info is up-to-date because that link is a few years old, but that seems to be the case.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept. I compressed the mp4 to 28 mb, just to be on the safe side, and that even made it work on Mobile Safari, even though I had understood that there the limit was flexible.